# CodeIgniter pagination class

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Feed::$pagination

Filename: controllers/feed.php

Line Number: 60

Fatal error: Call to a member function create_links() on a non-object in /var/www/html/socializator/application/controllers/feed.php on line 60

Comment: please we need some code ;) (controller + view)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$this->load->library('pagination');

$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/index.php/test/page/';
$config['total_rows'] = 200;
$config['per_page'] = 20; 

$this->pagination->initialize($config); 

echo $this->pagination->create_links();
```

check this link for more info 
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/pagination.html